# STAX Parser and Arraylist

Tags: java, xml, arraylist, jfreechart, stax

I used `ArrayList` and Stax parser to extract data from XML file.
This is how each row looks in my XML file (each row contains different data):

```
<row>
  <millis>1000</millis>
  <stamp> 1273010254</stamp>
  <datetime> 2010/5/4 21:57:34</datetime>
  <light> 333</light>
  <temp> 78.32</temp>
  <vcc> 3.54</vcc>
</row>
```

Here is an `ArrayList` I am using:

```
public List<Measurement> readMeasurements(String xmlFile) {

        List<Measurement> measurements = new ArrayList<Measurement>();
        Measurement measurement = null;
```

Here is piece of code from Stax Parser class:

```
if (xmlEvent.isStartElement()){
                    StartElement startElement = xmlEvent.asStartElement();
                    if(startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("row")){
                        measurement = new Measurement();
                    }
                    else if(startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("millis")){
                        xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
                        measurement.setMillis(xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData());
```

and so on...

Still new in programming so my question is: How to calculate (find mean/average) of "light" or "millis" elements from my `ArrayList` and display it in a textbox. Don't need to be displayed at textbox but will be easier for me, because I will presenting data from textbox using `JFreeChart`.

I did some research and I read that IndexOf may be helpful since I am using equal in my code, but I am not sure how to manipulate specific element of my `ArrayList`.

Comment: How would you calculate those things using any other `ArrayList`?  Seems you've posted a bunch of code that's not related to your actual question...

Comment: I just want to use all data from "millis" or "light" elements and calculate it. I don't know how to access these elements data from my arraylist.

Answer (score 1):

Because [`List<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) implements [`Iterable<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), you can use a [*for-each*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) loop to iterate over the `List<Measurement>` obtained from parsing and calculate the [average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average).

```
int sum = 0;
for (Measurement m : measurements) {
    sum += m.getSomeValue();
}
// find average
```